# non-tls stmp proxy to tls smtp server?

Tags: email, ssl, proxy, smtp

My problem is that I am dealing with an e-commerce software that is only capable of sending mails through simple smtp.

The only mailservers available are Gmail and Amazon S3.

Unfortunately I cannot change this.

How can I make this work?

I thought of some smtp proxy that accepts insecure connections and relays to a secure smtp server.

Is there any package that does that? As easy as possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to implement an SMTP proxy, what you need, is a standard SMTP Mail Relay.  Install Exim or Postfix or something of that ilk, secure it, configure your app to send mail to it, and then have Exim or Postfix route mail to the destination, either through Gmail and Amazon S3 or directly.

When you say 'the only mail servers available are Gmail and Amazon S3' why is that?

Comment: well its an external requirement, i dont know why... its for a company. maby they want to keep track of sending mails in some way they are used to..